# Get a picture from Computer and post it on Facebook multiple pages at a time using PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

**ISSUE**:If i am using graph URL method as in facebook developer's blog here [LINK](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/),i am just able to post to a single page at a time(i want to be able to post pictures to all the selected pages of my application user).[developing an application to let users post to multiple pages at a time].So i am not using that method,and below is my method.

**Using** Heroku app engine,it doesn't allow to permanently store uploaded files on its server.so i can't save photos.i.e please don't refer move_uploaded_file().

Here's the code for html form field:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="poster.php" method="POST">
<p>Please choose a photo: </p>
<input name="source" type="file">
<p>Add Description </p>
<input name="message" type="text" value=""> 
<input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

Here's the poster.php code:

```
<?php
require "facebook.php" ;
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => '',
'secret' => '',
'cookie' =>true,
));
if(session_id()){}
else{session_start();}
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport("http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
$x=realpath($_FILES['source']['tmp_name']);
$parameters = array('message' => $_POST['message'],'source' =>'@' . $x );
$parameters['access_token'] = $_SESSION['active']['access_token'];
$check=$facebook->api('/me/photos','POST',$parameters);
$redirecting="https://apps.facebook.com/pagecron/manage.php";
echo "<script>top.window.location='".$redirecting."';</script>";
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry answering my own question,but it will be really helpful a lot to all others....first of all..i am happy i did it!!!

Here is wat the mistake was...
 Replace  `$facebook->setFileUploadSupport("http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);`

with

`$facebook->setFileUploadSupport("http://apps.facebook.com/myappname");`

Answer (score 2):

Yes this should work because the full path will build a link of the image.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but you may try this -

```
$parameters = array(
     'message' => $_POST['message'],
     'picture' => '@' . $path,
     'link' => $_POST['link'],
     'name' => $_POST['name'],
     'caption' => $_POST['caption'],
     'description' => $_POST['description']
      );
```

If this doesn't solve your problem, you can share the code of API calling.

Comment: ok i am just trying it.having a lil confusion,`$path = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];` gives the path name along with file name or just the file name??

Comment: don't use this, give actual path to the file and then use the code I mentioned in comment

Comment: Can you search SO for that.